# Delay after RCTP command on GMail

Tags: smtp, gmail

I want to create a SMTP validation on registration at my website, but I got a strange behavior on GMail SMTP servers.
The validation looks like sending emails: after establishing connection with SMTP server I send commands **EHLO**, **HELO**, **MAIL FROM**, **RCPT TO** and **QUIT**.
Commands like **HELO** and **MAIL FROM** not take many time, but command **RCPT TO** can take about 3 seconds on GMail. For example, on several others servers this command takes only 200-300ms.

Also, if I check an existing email address, **RCTP** command takes only 600-900ms, but this delay always takes more then 3 seconds for unexisting address.

I think, this delay is an antispam behavior, but how I can bypass it?
My domain already has correct **TXT-SPF** and **SPF** records. My server not listed in any spam lists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the delay that you're reporting after RCPT TO.  I run a mail server that logs the transcript with the remote MTA for every delivery.  Looking at a few recent deliveries to gmail addresses, I see that the server for gmail responded with a 250 OK almost immediately after RCPT TO from my side.  See below.  (email addresses and IP's anonymized to protect the innocent!).

```
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT DNS MX record lookup for gmail.com:
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT MX1=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, MX2=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, MX3=alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT Attempting SMTP connection from smtp.myserver.com [x.x.x.x] to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.64.27] on port 25
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT Delivery id 813435, process id 21352
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT received from remotehost: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP b5si18818338obh.145 - gsmtp
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT smtp.myserver.com sent: EHLO smtp.myserver.com
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT received from remotehost: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [x.x.x.x]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 PIPELINING
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT smtp.myserver.com sent: STARTTLS
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT received from remotehost: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT starting TLS...
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT TLS Enabled.
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT smtp.myserver.com sent: EHLO smtp.myserver.com
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT received from remotehost: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [x.x.x.x]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 PIPELINING
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT smtp.myserver.com sent: MAIL FROM: <sender@sender.com>
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT received from remotehost: 250 2.1.0 OK b5si18818338obh.145 - gsmtp
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT smtp.myserver.com sent: RCPT TO: <recipient@gmail.com>
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT received from remotehost: 250 2.1.5 OK b5si18818338obh.145 - gsmtp
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT smtp.myserver.com sent: DATA
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT received from remotehost: 354  Go ahead b5si18818338obh.145 - gsmtp
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT [sending message...] (14871 bytes)
Tue Jul 23 16:01:52 2013 GMT [message sent]
Tue Jul 23 16:01:53 2013 GMT received from remotehost: 250 2.0.0 OK 1374595312 b5si18818338obh.145 - gsmtp
```

Comment: You connect to local SMTP server and it does not have a delay between those operations. If the recipient does not exists, the local SMTP server sends error report to your back address later.
But I connect directly to (for example) gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

Comment: No, this transcript is not for a connection to a `local` smtp server.  This is for a connection to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.64.27], which is a gmail MX server, pointed to by an MX record for gmail.com.  See the third line from the top above.

Comment: Try to send email to **surfhmxakelhlfaiuwlehr123maiw3yraiwdasjbd@gmail.com**, for example. Your SMTP server also returns status 250 on RCTP command. It is not a validation.

Comment: Yes.  I tried sending a message to surfhmxakelhlfaiuwlehr123maiw3yraiwdasjbd@gmail.com and I got a 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist error back from the gmail MX server.  See http://pastebin.com/GpvTWVtW for transcript.

Comment: Very interesting... You have no delay.
What SMTP software you using for testing?

Comment: I run www.ultrasmtp.com.  If you're interested in running the same test, your can sign up for a free trial account and send some messages, and you'll get a transcript back like the one I posted.

Comment: It's not a realtime validation. This service doesn't give status 550 directly.

Comment: That's correct.  The service is for sending mail over SMTP, not for real time validation.  But, validation could be done the same way, stopping after RCPT TO.  And, as you can see, there is little/no delay.